# SQL query to create an analytics funnel

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table named `analytics`, to it contains the following columns:

- `pid` - a website this row belongs to
- `pg` - current page
- `prev` - previous page the user visited (before navigating to the current page)
- `created` - string date of when this row was created

I need to calculate a funnel (the number of users that went from page A to page B and after that to page C (i.e. A -> B -> C...)).
As a database, I use Clickhouse with the MergeTree engine for this table.

Here's an example of a query that I tried (but it calculates the funnel wrong, instead of `A - > B -> C` it calculates the funnel as `A -> B`, `B -> C` (which is wrong, because there may be users navigated to the B page from X and Z sources)):

```js
const query = `
  SELECT
    count() AS count
  FROM analytics
  WHERE
    pid = {pid:FixedString(12)}
    AND created BETWEEN {groupFrom:String} AND {groupTo:String}
    AND pg = {page:String}
    ${pages.length > 1 ? `AND prev = {prevPage:String}` : ''}
`

const promises = pages.map(async (page, index) => {
  const prevPage = index > 0 ? pages[index - 1] : null
  const result = await clickhouse
    .query(query, { params: { ...params, page, prevPage } })
    .toPromise()
  return result[0].count
})

await Promise.all(promises)
```

I suppose that problem may be fixed by using INNER JOINs, so here's a query I created later:

```sql
SELECT
  count(t0), count(t1), count(t2)
FROM analytics as t0
INNER JOIN analytics as t1 ON t0.pg = t1.prev AND t0.pid = t1.pid
INNER JOIN analytics as t2 ON t1.pg = t2.prev AND t1.pid = t2.pid
WHERE t0.pid = 'example.com'
  AND t0.created BETWEEN '2023-05-13' AND '2023-07-13'
  AND t0.pg = 'pageA'
  AND t1.pg = 'pageB'
  AND t2.pg = 'pageC';
```

It throws an error that t1, t2, t3 are missing, if I replace `count(t0), count(t1), count(t2)` with `*` - the query will fail to execute with the `Memory limit (total) exceeded` error code.

How can I fix this query? Is there another, more optimal way to implement it?

Answer (score -1):

have you looked at the windowFunnel function? it is designed for this very problem

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. As it’s written, your answer doesn’t give enough information that the average reader is going to understand how to use it to solve a similar problem. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details and to clarify your recommendation for the benefit of the community?** Regards.